# How can I add an external library to web components that are generated using Vue CLI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, web-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to Vue.js and using it to create web-components. This is the CLI command to build all of the components at once:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\vue-cli-service build --target wc --name sky 'src\components\*.vue'
```

Its building a sky.js file containing all of the components.

The problem is that I want to use a UI library like Vuetify or BootstrapVue. Where should I import these libraries? Importing them into each component make the generated js file so big!

Thanks